# (Excel) Create dynamic path in index/match without using indirect

Tags: excel, performance, excel-formula, index-match

I've got two tabs in a workbook, a directory tab and a report list tab.  In the directory tab, I have a list of worker identifiers, each of which is associated with a file path.  In the report list tab, I have a list of assignment identifiers, each of which is associated with one of the worker identifiers.

A simplified example of the two tabs:

Directory:

| A (*Worker ID*) | B (*Path*) |
| --- | --- |
| abc | E:\Group\Assignments\[andy worklog.xlsx] |
| def | E:\Group\Assignments\[don worklog.xlsx] |
| ... | ... |

The paths are formatted with the brackets as shown.

Report List:

| A (*Assignment ID*) | B (*Worker*) |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | abc |
| 222222 | abc |
| 325456 | def |
| 456789 | abc |
| ... | ... |

My goal is to, on the report tab, use the associated worker identifier for each assignment to fetch the path to the relevant worklog file, and use that path to do an index/match to pull data from the file.  Right now I'm doing it in two steps/cells (although I realize I could do it in one, just not certain if there is any computational efficiency difference).  In the first cell (let's say it's cell C2, I fetch the relevant file path:

`=INDEX(Directory!$B:$B,MATCH('Report List'!$B2,Directory!$A:$A,0))`

This works as expected, and displays the path exactly as shown in the table above.

In the second cell (call it D2), I try to pull data from that file:

`=INDEX("'" & $C2 & "Sheet 1'!$F:$F",MATCH('Report List'!$A2,"'" & $C2 & "Sheet 1'!$A:A",0))`

This is where I get a value error.  In the Evaluate Formula tool, I can see that the first argument in the INDEX() and MATCH() functions resolves as expected:

> 'E:\Group\Assignments[andy worklog.xlsx]Sheet 1'!$F:$F

(This is the first argument for INDEX(), it is the same in MATCH() except $A:$A instead of $F:$F).

After that, it only gives the error, so I'm not sure what is going wrong.  Upon initially testing the formula, it opens the file explorer like it's asking me to navigate to the file, but that isn't ideal since there are several dozen different files.  I know that INDIRECT() is useful when trying to do dynamic paths, but this workbook is fairly large and I'm worried about the performance implications of a volatile function.

So I've got a few questions:

1. What is going wrong to give me the error?
2. Is it more efficient (performance-wise) to separate this into two steps/cells/columns as shown, or should I combine it all into one after I've got the kinks worked out?  My initial thought was that since I'm using that path multiple times in the index/match, it might be more efficient to fetch it first before using it, but I could be completely wrong.
3. Is it worth it (or even possible) to avoid using INDIRECT()?  To give you an idea, there are several thousand rows in the Report List tab, and ~50 worker IDs/linked files.

Comment: 1. INDEX and MATCH do not accept strings as references, that is what INDIRECT is for. 2. It is a toss up, niether is more advantageous than the other so what ever works for you. 3. With the current setup it is not possible(without vba) to do this without INDIRECT.  So try it and see if it adversely effects your performance.  But also note that INDIRECT requires the referenced workbook to be open.

Comment: I didn't realize that INDIRECT requires the workbook to be open.  That could also be problematic (since there are ~50 workbooks).  Any idea how I would do this using vba (or where to point me to find out)?